# Hover display element by CSS

Tags: html, css

I couldn't find the reason why my hover display code doesn't work.
What I intended was : If I hover `.nav_menu_text` , display #hide_menu .
Is it due to display flex? I found many questions about this issue but failed to find out the reason.

```css
/* navbar */

.navbar {
    width: 2560px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
}

.nav_logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left: 370px;    
    font-size: 22px;
}

.nav_menublock {
    width: 670px;
    height: 19px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 489px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav_menu_text {
    width: 107px;
    height: 19px;
}

.nav_menu_text:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.nav_menu_text:hover #hide_menu {
    display:block;
}

/* dropdown */

#hide_menu {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown_menu {
    height: 308px;
    width: 678px;
    margin-left: 1007px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!-- navbar -->
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="nav_logo">
        logo
    </div>
    <div class="nav_menublock">
        <div class="nav_menu_text">text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_lang">
        <div>ENG</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- hover menu bar -->
<div id="hide_menu">
    <div class="dropdown_menu">
        <div class="dropdown_menu_vertical" id="menu_1">
            <div class="vertical_text">
                <div class="vertical_text_txt">menu</div>>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can simply use javascript onmouseover event to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

When you have `.nav_menu_text:hover #hide_menu` in your CSS, it looks for a child of `.nav_menu_text` called `#hide_menu`, but finds nothing. Your hidden menu is elsewhere on the page.

If you put it inside the element you're hovering over, then it will work.
Like this:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="nav_logo">
        logo
    </div>
    <div class="nav_menublock">
        <div class="nav_menu_text">text

            <div id="hide_menu">
                <div class="dropdown_menu">
                    <div class="dropdown_menu_vertical" id="menu_1">
                        <div class="vertical_text">
                            <div class="vertical_text_txt">menu</div>>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_lang">
        <div>ENG</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You'll also have to adjust your margin-left to get the contents of the menu where you want them, because now the starting point will be at `div class="nav_menu_text"`, rather than the left edge of the whole window.